# sql one to many including itself?

Tags: sql, one-to-many

Struggling with a one to many that also includes the master record without having to add a detail record that references itself?

```
select * from master m
inner join detail d on d.id2 = m.id
where d.id1 = 1
```

This will return

```
2,John,1,2
4,Nancy,1,4
```

How do I get it to also return

```
1,Jim,nul,nul
```

If I add 1,1 record to the below detail it works, but was hoping to get around that.

Master

```
1,Jim
2,John
3,Fred
4,Nancy
5,Jen
```

Detail

```
1,2
1,4
3,5
```

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: Look at left join. Just why not you get 5, jen, 3 ,5 in the output?

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and still can't understand what you want to do. Please edit your question with the relevant ddl + dml statements for the sample data

Comment: Hi SMA,  Not sure what you are asking about 5, jen

Comment: Hi Zohar,  not sure what part of the ddl or dml to provide.  Do you want the sql to create the table with the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a more complicated `on` expression:

```
select *
from master m inner join
     detail d
     on d.id2 = m.id or d.id1 = m.id
where d.id1 = 1;
```

You could also write this as:

```
     on m.id in (d.id1, d.id2)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  That was one of my attempts the problem is then I get the first value repeated. 1,Jim,1,2 * 2,John,1,2 * 1,Jim,1,4 * 4,Nancy,1,4

Comment: Given the data posted in your question, I don't quite see how the first query would returned duplicated results.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?